# Jason/AgentSpeak trying to synchronize agents

Tags: artificial-intelligence, agent

Hello I am trying to implement a tree sort for 8 numbers. I created 15 tree nodes agents and one manager agent. What I am trying to achieve is to synchronize leaves in the tree and send their generated numbers to manager node. My problem is that in my for cycle, the leaves are not synchronized so manager is waiting for next leaf but that leaf may send it's number already. Is there a way to synchronize these leaves so the manager waits for each leaf and then prints out received numbers?

Here are the agents:

treeSort.mas2j

```
MAS treeSort {
    infrastructure: Centralised
    agents:
        manager;
        agent#15;
}
```

manager.asl:

```
!start.
+!start : true <-
    for ( .range(I,8,15) ) {
        .concat("agent",I,TempAgent);
        .print("waiting from ",TempAgent);
        .wait(recievedNum(Y,X) & Y=TempAgent);
        .print("from ",Y," recvd ",X);    
    };
    .println(" done").
```

agent.asl

```
!start.

@p1 +!start : .my_name(agent8) | .my_name(agent9)| .my_name(agent10)|.my_name(agent11)
        | .my_name(agent12) | .my_name(agent13) | .my_name(agent14) |my_name(agent15) <- +myNum(math.round(math.random(100)));
    ?myNum(X);
    +iam(leaf);
    .my_name(Y);
    .send(manager, tell, recievedNum(Y,X)).

@p2 +!start : .my_name(agent7) | .my_name(agent6)|  .my_name(agent5) |.my_name(agent4)
        | .my_name(agent3) | .my_name(agent2) <- +iam(node).

@p3 +!start : .my_name(agent1) <- +iam(root).
```

Comment: Hi, are you sure the manager is waiting forever in some cases? 

.wait(<e>) waits until the condition is true, however, if it is already true, it does not wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really tricky! I was using Jason 2.1 and I have experienced some unstable results. From Jason 2.2a and 2.3 SNAPSHOT actually, your original idea is working just fixing some typos and including ".term2string(YT,TempAgent);" and removing "& Y=TempAgent" as proposed by Jomi. But, to ensure that all agents are ready and also the creation of random numbers being done also in right sequence I propose the following code:

treeSort.mas2j

```
MAS treeSort {
    infrastructure: Centralised
    agents:
        manager;
        agent#15;
}
```

manager.asl

```
!start.

+!start : .count(hi[_],N) & N >= 15 <- //wait for all agents
    for ( .range(I,8,15) ) {
        .concat("agent",I,TempAgent);
        .print("waiting from ",TempAgent);
        .term2string(YT,TempAgent);
        .send(TempAgent,achieve,start);
        .wait({+newMsg(YT,X)},5000);
        .print("from ",YT," recvd ",X); 
    };
    .println(" done"). 

+!start <-
    .wait(100);
    !start.

+hi.

+recievedNum(YT,X) <-
    -+newMsg(YT,X).
```

agent.asl

```
!hi.

+!hi <- .send(manager, tell, hi).

@p1 +!start : .my_name(agent8) | .my_name(agent9)| .my_name(agent10)|.my_name(agent11)
        | .my_name(agent12) | .my_name(agent13) | .my_name(agent14) |.my_name(agent15) <- +myNum(math.round(math.random(100)));
    ?myNum(X);
    +iam(leaf);
    .my_name(Y);
    .send(manager, tell, recievedNum(Y,X)).

@p2 +!start : .my_name(agent7) | .my_name(agent6)|  .my_name(agent5) |.my_name(agent4)
        | .my_name(agent3) | .my_name(agent2) <- +iam(node).

@p3 +!start : .my_name(agent1) <- +iam(root).
```

Answer (score 1):

The .concat produces a string (TempAgent is thus a string), but the first argument of receivedNum is an atom and both do no unify. Solution:

```
!start.
+!start : true <-
    for ( .range(I,8,15) ) {
        .concat("agent",I,TempAgent);
        .print("waiting from ",TempAgent);
        .term2string(YT,TempAgent);
        .wait(recievedNum(YT,X));
        .print("from ",YT," recvd ",X);    
    };
    .println(" done").
```

Comment: This was one bug, but it does not solve the problem, somehow the `.wait()` is non blocking so the manager already have all the numbers in database but is still waiting for that one first agent

Comment: tha is strange, I tested the above code in my machie and it works! (notice that there is a bug in the agent.asl: it lacks a "." before my_name(agent15).

Comment: Can you please upload your screenshot of program output, because mine looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/5bI2N5N . And as I said the manager already have all numbers from agents in his database: https://imgur.com/a/ZZ35pD9 . That missing "." was a mistake done by pasting code.

Comment: Edit: This is new screen of the output - https://imgur.com/a/ewOAuxv as you can see, he already received all numbers but still waits for the number from agent 9, but because he received number from him already when waiting for agent 8, he will never stop waiting

Comment: This solution also worked for me. From original code, besides the use of .term2string and a typo on agent.asl regarding .my_name function, I had used rec-E-I-ved instead of rec-I-E-ved.

Answer (score 1):

To synchronize the agents, the performative askOne is better: it stops the execution of the intention until an answer is received. For instance, the manager:

```
!start.
+!start : true <-
    .wait(500); // **** waits a bit for agents to start
    for ( .range(I,8,15) ) {
        .concat("agent",I,TempAgent);
        .print("waiting from ",TempAgent);
        .term2string(YT,TempAgent);
        .send(YT,askOne,num(_),num(X)); // **** waits for the answer
        .print("from ",YT," recvd ",X);
    };
    .println(" done").
```

and the agent code:

```
!start.

@p1 +!start : .my_name(agent8) | .my_name(agent9)| .my_name(agent10)|.my_name(agent11)
        | .my_name(agent12) | .my_name(agent13) | .my_name(agent14) | .my_name(agent15)
<- +num(math.round(math.random(100))); // *** just add the belief (the askOne protocol will look for it)
   +iam(leaf).

@p2 +!start : .my_name(agent7) | .my_name(agent6)|  .my_name(agent5) |.my_name(agent4)
        | .my_name(agent3) | .my_name(agent2) 
<- +iam(node).

@p3 +!start : .my_name(agent1) <- +iam(root).
```